# Storing DNA in Swift

Tags: optimization, query-optimization, storage, sparse-matrix, dna-sequence

I'm going to write an application for dealing with raw DNA data samples, as the files you get from MyHeritage, Ancestry, FamilyTreeDNA, 23&me etc. Each of these files are basically a CSV-file with some quirks, and asked about decoding them in another question I posted earlier.

Now for the next part. When I have parsed/decoded those files, I want to put the DNA data in a database, so that I can compare one persons DNA to that of another person. It's a lot of data, but not more than most computers can handle.

In memory, I can have the full DNA for both persons, and compare them, and then create ArraySlices for the segments of DNA data that overlap, but ArraySlices aren't suitable for storage, In memory the ArraySlice can't exist by itself. It's just a reference into the full array, so if I would flatten the ArraySlice I would still get the whole array, even for the segments that don't match.

Each person shall have their full DNA on backing store, and can be read into memory, but how would you store the matching segments?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
//Bucket is the term FamilyTreeDNA for indicating whether the DNA match is on the maternal or paternal chromosome.
enum Bucket {
    case .maternal
    case .paternal
}

//THe first 22 chromosome pairs are just numbered from 1 to 22, but the last two are X and Y, so I use a String for storing chromosome "number"

struct SharedSegment {
    let onChromosome: String
    let bucket: Bucket
    let range: Range<UInt>
}
```

I don't care if it takes more disk space, but I want to have lightning fast comparisons of DNA, so that I can compare all the DNA for all the individuals in a datavase, without it taking months to do so. Also storage space for the full DNA to make comparisons.

At the first stage I'm just building an app for storing the DNA kits I administer, but I already have plans for a services of type Gedmatch and DNAPainter if you have tried them. This means it's a services where people can upload their DNA to be compared to other peoples DNA, and lets says a million people upload their DNA to this service, and each of them should have their DNA compared to the other 999'999 people. The number of comparison will be huge, so my primary focus is on performance. Each file with raw DNA data will contain about 400-950 thousand lines of DNA data.

Each line will contain the chromosome number, the RSID, the position within the chromosome and a genotype. The latter is two letters "AA", "AC", "CT" etc. There are four different letters A, C, G and T. The reason there are two letter for each position is that you have chromosome pairs, where there is one chromosome inherited from the father and one from the mother, and there is one letter from each of those two chromosomes. Of course I can store them as just a string of  characters, but there are chances of errors, so I would like to represent them in code as

```
enum Aminoacid {
    noCall = 0
    case A
    case C
    case G
    case T
}
```

When sequencing DNA there are sometimes problem, and the sequencing equipment can't determine which amino acid it is in a certain position. This is called a "no call", therefore the case noCall in the enum. in the raw DNA file this is represented by a dash, so it can say in the results "-A"m which means that one of the parents had an A in that position, and the other could not be determined.

Is there any possibility to squeeze them together in 4 bits (nybble), so that I can store two of these letter per byte?It's even possible to squeeze into 3 bits, but I can't get three letters into a byte anyway. It solve be two letter á 3 birs each and two bits wasted in every byte, so I could just as well use 4 bits per amino acid. There are Uint64, Uint32, Uint16 and Uint8 in Swift, but no Uint4, which would be ideal for this case. I'm also thinking about whether to store the two letter from the maternal and paternal chromosome together or if U should split them into separate array One array for maternal DNA and one for paternal). There is a problem with that approach, and that is it's impossible to tell if the first letter on each row is maternal or paternal, until you have the DNA from at least one of the parents to compare with. In absence of their DNA, I would have to have a third array to store both letters in, until I can determine swhich one is maternal end paternal respectively. I'm trying to come up with the most effective way of storing this, to make the comparisons super fast.

In one way I don't like using enums, and that is because I will have to convert them to rawValue, do I can do something like

```
var genotype = Aminoacid.A.rawValue << 4 + Aminoacid.G.rawValue
```

As far as I can see that's the best way to squeeze two of these into ont byte, since there's no UInt4.

I'm not so fond of having lots of .rawValue all over my code. I would like to have only Aminoacid.A << 4 + Aminoacid.G, but unfortunately I don't think this is possible. Maybe there is a beter way to store these sequences of amino acids in the database, like enums with associated values or something. I don't know how efficient associated values till be, when working with such large data sets.

If there is anyone out there, that wants to collaborate on this project, that is so far just a hobby project, but I have plans for making a business out of it eventually. This means I can't employ anyone to do this, but if you're working on similar projects then let me know. We can make better things together. Just be aware that I'm writing in Swift, and I'm going to deploy on macOS, but Swift is also available for other platforms, so coders for Linux and Windows are equally welcome to work on a joint project.

This became a little offtopic. My question was about storage of raw DNA and shared segments in a way that is optimal for fast search and comparison of huge amounts of DNA.I probably won't use CoreData for storage, since I would like to keep the options for porting to other platforms than Apples. At the moment I'm using CoreData to experiment a little with storing DNA in different ways.

Comment: DNA doesn't have amino acids in it. You should consider looking at the indexing and variant storage solutions that NCBI has, for example.

Comment: Sorry! I meant nucleases of course. Thanks for the tip though! I'll look into it.